# Calculating the coefficient of a generating function

Tags: combinatorics

> Calculate the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $$\frac{1+x^3}{1-2x+x^3-x^4}$$

I am unsure how to even start and would appreciate a hint? I haven't dealt with problems like this (complicated) before.

Comment: So I would start by attempting to perform polynomial long division such that the power of $x$ increases with each next term.  Keep performing long division, even if there is a remainder, like dividing $1/7$ into a decimal format.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Write $$ \frac{1 + x^3}{1 - 2x + x^3 - x^4} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$, multiply the denominator on both sides of the equation and compare coefficients. Do you get a recurrence relation?

Comment: +1 Yes. A little lateral thinking: instead of using a generating function to solve a recurrence relation, use a recurrence relation to get the coefficients in a function.

Comment: I am not getting a recurrence per say. But, I have that, $a_3 = 2a_2$ and that $a_0 = 1$.

Comment: One term after multiplying both sides by the denominator is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -2a_nx^{n+1}$. You can rewrite this as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -2a_{n-1}x^{n}$

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped, or I'll complete the answer if needed